# Electron app with Facebook SDK

Tags: electron

My electron app needs Facebook login. However there are 2 issues I am facing:

1. Facebook requires an OAuth redirect URI, which does not exist in the context of the desktop app.
2. Facebook login requires cookies.

   - For the first issue, in dev mode I serve the html via a dev-server (webpack), so I can kinda cheat by using the `localhost:3000` as redirect URI. However, I have no idea how I can ship this app in production.
   - For the second issue, I tried to install this [electron-cookies module[(https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-cookies), but the issue is not resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Khanetor.

What you need is to set webPreferences.webSecurity to false, please see snippet below:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    frame: true,
    webPreferences: {
        webSecurity: false,
        plugins: true
    }
});
```

I am doing Facebook auth within Electron myself now, after overcoming cookies issue there is another problem to deal - to login, facebook opens new window and once you logged in it sends postMessage to other windows and closes. But postMessages do not work the same in the Electron as it does in normal browser..

Comment: Yes, it possible to have facebook auth url with redirection back to localhost address. Basically you add the "login" button which leads to that url, and after authenticating ir redirects user back to localhost.

Comment: for me when using a `<webview>` i needed to add `allowpopups disablewebsecurity` to make it work

Answer (score 4):

Don't use localhost if you don't need to. Follow FB's docs instead:

redirect_uri. The URL that you want to redirect the person logging in back to. This URL will capture the response from the Login Dialog. If you are using this in a webview within a desktop app, this must be set to https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html. You con confirm that this URL is set for your app by going to the App Dashboard, clicking Facebook Login in the right-hand menu, and checking the Valid OAuth redirect URIs in the Client OAuth Settings section.

(1) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow

EDIT: I've made this work, if you have more questions ask away.

Comment: Can i use my own redirect url in this case ?  I am wonering why "this must be set to" the specific facebook success page ?